# How can I send in a variable a local image from my backend to my php front.blade with html?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am programming an email and I need to send an image to my front, I send it from a variable because I have a condition that changes the image that the variable contains. This is the condition code

```
$countGWS = substr_count($empresa_usuario, 'GRUPO WATT SOLAR');
        error_log($countGWS);
        $countMS = substr_count($empresa_usuario, 'MAYORISTA PANELES SOLARES');
        error_log($countMS);

       
        $empresa = 0;
        $directory = "";
        if($countGWS > 0 && $countMS > 0){
            echo "MAYORISTA PANELES SOLARES y GRUPO WATT SOLAR!!!";
            $empresa = 1;
            error_log($empresa);
            $directory='coreui/public/img/brand/mpanesSolar.png';

        }elseif($countGWS > 0 && $countMS == 0) {
            echo "GRUPO WATT SOLAR!!!";
            $empresa = 2;
            error_log($empresa);
            $directory='coreui/public/img/brand/gwattsolar.jpeg';

        }elseif($countMS > 0 && $countGWS == 0){
            echo "MAYORISTA PANELES SOLARES!!!";
            $empresa = 3;
            error_log($empresa);
            $directory='coreui/public/img/brand/gwsymsjpg.jpg';
        }
```

Here I send the information to my .blade and my variables with the data, my directory variable which is the one that contains the image

```
if (count($fecha_nacimiento) > 0) {
            error_log(" lo envie");
            Mail::send('mails/cumple', compact('nombre_cumple','directory'), function ($mail) {
                $mail->from('energiasolar@grupowattsolar.com');
                $mail->to('auxsistemas@grupowattsolar.com');
                $mail->subject("Feliz Cumpleaños!!!");
                $mail->headers = array(
                    'From' => 'Departamento de Recursos Humanos'
                );
            });             
        }
```

I have tried to receive the image from my blade but I have not achieved anything, I have tried with each of these. I do not know what else to do, I would be very grateful if you help me.

```
<img src="{{$directory->getPath()}}" alt="Cotizacion" style="max-width:600px;width:100%" /> 

<img src="{{ storage_path('app/public/brand/wattsolar-logo.png') }}" alt="Portada" width="500" height="200" /> 

<img src="{{ storage_path('public/img/brand/gwsymsjpg.jpg') }}" alt="Portada" width="500" height="200" />

<img src="{{ asset('public/img/brand/gwsymsjpg.jpg') }}" alt="tag">

<img src={{directory}} alt="Logo" height="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

the url for you image depends where you have placed your image.

### public folder

if the image was placed into the public folder:
e.g. `project/public/img/brand/gwsymsjpg.jpg`
then you can access it with `asset('img/brand/gwsymsjpg.jpg')`

### storage folder

if the image was placed into the storage folder:
e.g. `project/storage/app/public/img/brand/gwsymsjpg.jpg`

they you have to execute `php artisan storage:link` first
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk 
this will create a symlink from public folder to your storage folder.

After that you can access it with `asset('storage/img/brand/gwsymsjpg.jpg')`